# Spacing problem with subscripts by using math symbols within glossary

Tags: math-mode, latex3, mathtools, glossary

I have a problem by using glossary. E.g. i define a math symbol as follows:

```
\newglossaryentry{spannungsvektor}{%
    name= Spannungsvektor,
    description=Spannungsvektor,
    sort=t, 
    user1={$\mathrm{N/m^2}$} ,
    user2={\ensuremath{[t_{i}]}}, 
    user3={\ensuremath{t}},
}
```

In the Latex dokument i cite to user3:

```
\glsuseriii{spannungsvektor}_i
```

This result differ from the result of the command

```
t_i
```

Is there a way to use glossary so that the output is the same as that of the classic commands?

I found a possible solution: glosmathtools
Actually i don't know if this is the answer, but it looks quite good.

Comment: As always on this site, please always provide full but minimal examples that others can copy and test as is. That makes it a lot easier to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Solution is:

```
\glsuseriii{spannungsvektor}[_i]
```

instead of using

```
\glsuseriii{spannungsvektor}_i
```

Comment: Is there a possibility to not add the optional argument to the link? I want to print for example T^{-1}, with T being the symbol. In this case, the ^{-1} is not part of the symbol but is included in the link and colored in the link color. The spacing without is bad and the minus overlaps with the italic T.